# Описать функцию, которая находит расстояние между двумя произвольными точками

Tags: c++, указатели, шаблоны-с++

Проинициализировать два массива, которые задают n точек координатами (X, Y) в двумерном пространстве. Описать функцию, которая находит расстояние между двумя произвольными точками.

При запуске следующий код выдает то -80, то 112, то 160. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <math.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int *x=new int [5] {1, 4, 6, 2, 1}; //создание массива из 5 к-т х
    int *y=new int [5] {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; //создание массива из 5 к-т у
    cout << "Расстояние между двумя точками:" << distance(x,y) << endl;
}

int distance(int *x,int* y, int size) //
{
    float d;
    d = sqrt(pow((x[1] - x[0]), 2) + pow((y[1] - y[0]), 2));
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Очередной привет от дикой манеры делать `using namespace std;`...

Comment: а как еще можно? я новичок

Comment: Не понял. Новичок или не новичок, вы сделали `using namespace std;` с какой-то целью. С какой?

Comment: Он сделал это с целью, чтобы выглядело наукообразно. (скопировал откуда-то)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то раз вы не объявили `distance` **до** использования, то компилятор поискал-поискал, да и воспользовался `distance` из стандартной библиотеки - искать расстояние между двумя итераторами...

Добавьте

```
int distance(int *x,int* y);
```

**перед** `int main()()`.